# Google Cloud Messaging Bridging Header import fails

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing Google Cloud Messaging in my Swift iOS app. 
I was following this guide: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift

First I changed the pods file, then I ran pod install. This worked fine.
Since Swift needs a bridging header to include the ObjC Library I extended my header like suggested in the guide to

```
#import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>
```

But the import fails - file not found.

I noticed the fact that CloudMessaging.h is not in the Google folder directly but in Google/CloudMessaging. Unfortunately the import of

```
#import <Google/CloudMessaging/CloudMessaging.h>
```

works neither.

Here is a screenshot of what my pods look like

[image]

Did anyone notice the same problem? Any Ideas to fix it?
Project builds fine except that the GCM classes are not found since the header is not found.

Digging deeper:

I tried to add CloudMessaging from scratch:
I ran pod init and changed the podfile to

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'Google Cloud Push iOS' do
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
end

target 'Google Cloud Push iOSTests' do

end
```

then it works

If I use my podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
#platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 0.14'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 0.7'
pod 'HanekeSwift'
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
```

the error remains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

updating cocoa pods fixes this issue

Comment: some how i fixed this issue. But after building that my project this error comes.
This file is present in my project. Please anyone tell me any fix. 

GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)' does not contain bitcode.

Comment: try to disable bitcode. google libs do not have it. like this dude sais: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32640217/1432320

Comment: Google added Bitcode on this data 2016-01-25 -- v1.2.0
Add Bitcode markers.