# This action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload an **Apple TV** App to the App Store for testing purposes, but I got the issue:

> This Action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)

as in the below image:

[image]

So what can I do?

Comment: Even i got the same error first time when I submitted. However when I tried again, it successfully got uploaded.

Comment: i had try many time but got same error every time

Comment: I got the error. but I tried again. it works.

Comment: I have try many time but got same error.
Then after 2 or 3 days i try to create Archive then generate ipa and Upload to App Store using Application Loader. And Upload Successfully.

Comment: That error is kind of random. I received the same error message. I just tried again and it worked this time. No changes needed.

Comment: Simplest workaround is to export the IPA file, then use Application Loader to do the upload to the App Store.

Comment: Strange thing happen...I tried to upload app using "Upload to appstore" and it give me same error as mentioned above and after that i didn't change anything and click on "Upload to appstore" again and app uploaded successfully..

Comment: it's a bug in xcode , try to upload it again , it happen to twice , i keep trying to upload it again and it work 
you may also uncheck for bitcode

Comment: Export the archive and upload with the Application loader under Xcode so you can see the real errors.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253741/40770 if the error persists.

Comment: Tried again after first error and it worked

Comment: I just had this issue with a watch app ... turns out 1/3 of my AppIDs was using a different team identifier then the other 2 ... recreating the AppId with proper team id, then remaking the associated provisioning profile, rebuilding and resubmitting solved it for me!

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803 it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296541/3704795 - This worked

Comment: I am adding this comment mostly so other people can arrive on this page by searching for the other error text that you might get (I got it on 1 June 2017): `"The iTunes Store is experiencing an internal server error. See http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ for information about major outages. ..."` Interestingly, when going to the status page, all the status indicators were green, but the iTunes Connect upload was failing nonetheless.

Comment: A lot of time it is just because you have not update your Xcode version...

Comment: in my case, it turn out to be full of disk space, and when I clean up some `garbage` it can upload with no problem. is this general code that indicate upload error whatever the reason?

Comment: `altool` command worked for me, refer to [Xcode help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036)

Answer (score 768, accepted):

This happens because Apple's servers may not be working correctly. Just wait and try later or next time. It will work for sure eventually.

Comment: Yes Problem in Apple Server.

Comment: So: be patient, try again.  Glad it's now an official answer on SO.  It could also be your internet connection.

Comment: This is crazy. This happens ALL the time. WTF.

Comment: @Marchy use Application Loader instead

Comment: Nice that this Apple service is free, ... oh wait, actually we pay 99$ per year ...

Comment: Use Application Loader - it seems to be much more reliable.

Comment: That's definitely NOT my internet connection. iOS app development with React Native is easy peasy till you hit xcode to publish the app.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Great Solution.working for me when i tried after some minutes again.Gratefulness :)

Comment: This is crazy. We almost NEVER not get this message. We've spent multiple days repeatedly trying to resubmit (which pretty much makes a machine useless due to the CPU pressure the compilation puts on) until it finally goes through. Is this EVERYONE's experience submitting to the AppStore these days?

Comment: Odd they went with a 22421. Seems like more of a 34654590 to me

Comment: Still happening in Fev 2017. Got it on 2nd attempt.

Comment: Still happening in March 2017.

Comment: April 2017 the same

Comment: Yup same old same old... :)

Comment: You have to love explaining to a client that apple servers are just being finicky

Comment: Yeah fun fun fun when you have a deadline ( -_-")

Comment: It is amazing how bad the whole experience of creating apps for Apple is. The whole thing is designed to piss developers.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk This happen with me also.This happen with Xcode 8 new update its has lots of issue Disgusting version of Xcode 8.

Comment: mai 2017 the same

Comment: trying from last week of April & today is 12 may

Comment: Today is May 27, 2017 and it's still happening. Wasted several hours for just uploading a build. This is unacceptable.

Comment: Me too - so I just regenerated certificates and all but to no avail.

Comment: same June 1st 2017 :( wasting time

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa Me too :( good thing is, we know its an apple problem. I hope you are not in a hurry.

Comment: same here, have been trying since yesterday... wasted a lot of time

Comment: @josh The app store status seems online per this: https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/, how do you know it is an apple problem

Comment: @user1019042 well it is a server problem, cause when you try to upload an archive and it doesn't work and 5 min later it works, it means is a Server problem. If it was a Xcode problem we weren't be able to upload the archive even if you tried a thousand times.

Comment: finally got mine to work using the detailed steps in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44307288/1019042

Comment: Same June 1st 2017

Comment: Same in 13th June '17 :p

Comment: 4th day with 5 attempts each day and still facing the same problem. :(

Comment: well at least I have an excuse for slacking on my task list and missing the push-to-prod deadline

Comment: Oh dear! I thought I need to sell my kidney for this too ;)

Comment: Same in 2017 June 26

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I followed your instructions. I did add the two factor authentification to my cloud account. Then I went back to the xcode's organiser and exported my app for distribution on app store. Next I launched the app loader and I used my app specific password. After a few minutes the upload process failed but this time with "ITMS-90168 The binary you uploaded was invalid". Despite of the error I don't think there's something wrong with my .ipa :(

Comment: Same in July 2017, finally uploaded after 2 days of regular retrying

Comment: While it did work the second time i tried, i think it is worth mentioning that unless you do things right (ex. increase build number), it will not work for sure.

Comment: same trying 03-Aug-17

Comment: 14-Nov-2017, it still happened... I never had this kind of issue while publish APP to GooglePlay, but it happened all the time with Apple, and they dare tell user to pay $99 for next year !?!?   APPLE SUCKS !

Comment: Still happening Feb. 2018

Comment: Hurrreeee tried the same on next day, and it worked.

Comment: I can't believe that such answers can gain such popularity.

Comment: @NiVeR `altool` worked for me as [Xcode help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036) suggests. Technically speaking, we can wait for Transporter App update to solve the problem.

Answer (score 191):

Just try exporting the iPA file and then upload that exported iPA file with application loader. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I have try this also but can't Upload exported ipa to App Store

Comment: I have tried everything mentioned here, but this solved my problem.

Comment: Tried all the solutions above (except rebooting!) and only this one worked. With Application loader it's fine. What's weird is that I have two targets for my app in the projet. The free app always works and the pro one always fail (it's basically the same app without ads). Only application loader fixed it.

Comment: This is the best solution ever. APLICATION LOADER solves the problem.

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and do a reboot. ;)

Comment: Application Loader to the rescue (after like a DAY of reboots, removing old builds from ITC, retries, certificate checking, removing derived data and blowing away a rejection notice (thought it might be blocking)).  Ultimately, Application Loader explained that my analysis file was too large to parse (just a warning though) - and done.

Comment: If not, at least it will show you a more detailed description/cause of any error for sure.

Comment: Experienced this for the first time today. Exported the iPA and uploaded using the Application Loader. It's the first time I've used the loader, but worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: I always use Application Loader but unfortunately this time I got following error: `Invalid iMessage App - Your iMessage app contains an invalid sticker pack.` Guess I have to move to the generic way of doing this. BTW @Bartłomiej Semańczyk answer worked. I tried again and it worked ;)

Comment: Application loader gave me more pointers about what was wrong with my archive (in my case the build number needed to be incremented). I also recommend this solution as you won't need to re-perform the exporting process if the upload fails. Thanks !

Comment: Exporting to IPA and using the application loader worked for me. Also gives some useful logs for debugging.

Comment: good ol' Application Loader.. still the most reliable solution in year 2018.

Answer (score 71):

There's another way to fix above error. Try this, it fixed it for me. Open Terminal and run:

```
cd ~  
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/  
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

Three above code line will update iTMSTransporter, then you can try uploading in XCode again.

Refs for more details: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This helped!

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This solved it for me... too bad Xcode can't manage this on its own

Comment: I did an experiment with this, below, for June 1, 2017  (scroll down to my answer).  Unfortunately it *does not* seem to be the root problem   :/

Comment: Worked for me one release, thank you... next release the error returned.

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me too!

Comment: Thanks this worked for me - should be the accepted answer, don't wait 1 day as suggested.

Answer (score 57):

*(As of May 23, 2018)*

**Step 1**

Open Xcode --> *Product* tab --> *Archive* --> *export* and save to desktop

**Step 2**

Open Xcode --> *Xcode* tab --> *Open Developer Tool* --> *Application Loader* >> double-click *Deliver YourApp* and select the recently exported .ipa file from your desktop

**Solved the issue every time =)**

Comment: What is "XCode tab"?

Comment: Answer: XCode Menu at the top left!

Comment: that worked for me as well, but i couldn't log in at first into app loader with my correct password, idk why but i had to make [app specific password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397) and use it instead

Comment: I can't find "export and save to desktop" option in this chain:  Open Xcode --> Product tab --> Archive --> export and save to desktop

Comment: @Aleksandr: once the project is finished archiving Xcode will open the "Organizer". This can also be accessed from "Window" tab --> "Organizer" ... once here, select the archive file you wish to upload to App Store and click on "Export" --> Save for Store --> Next --> Next --> (wait to finish) --> save to Desktop

Comment: I have found it already, but thanks, hope it will help somebody.

Comment: @Aleksandr out of curiosity, what part did you not figure out initially? Where the export button was or that it was inside Organizer?

Comment: @BennyTheNerd that it was inside Organizer, in this chain "Open Xcode --> Product tab --> Archive --> export and save to desktop" it is not explicit will it be on new organizer screen or same before. Let's don't off topic. Thank you.

Comment: This is the best answer, hands down.

Answer (score 46):

As with all thing Xcode related. A simple reboot fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I just restarted xocde and it fixed this for me (xcode 8)

Comment: Multiple tries failed, but first after reboot worked.  This suggests to me that it  might not be just a problem on the server end.

Comment: @Phil_Ken_Sebben Exactly the same for me, I now have to reboot every time I want to submit ...

Comment: I think apple is the one who needs to reboot their server !

Answer (score 28):

Hey i have same issue when i am trying to upload IPA on Appstore. I solved it when i checked that my Distribution provisioning profile was invalid. So just update provisioning profile,download then install and restart Xcode. Now archive and upload it on Appstore it will be done.

OR

Create IPA and upload via Application Loader.

Good luck.

Comment: I have check my certificates valid. But still i can't upload my app to app store

Comment: I always use Application Loader but unfortunately this time I got following error: `Invalid iMessage App - Your iMessage app contains an invalid sticker pack.` Guess I have to move to the generic way of doing this. BTW @Bartłomiej Semańczyk answer worked. I tried again and it worked ;)

Answer (score 19):

**Will work for 100% sure.** I had the same issue but its solved by below steps:

1. Delete all profiles from: ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
2. Delete developer account from Xcode >> Preference >> Account >> Delete your Apple Id
3. Delete derived data
4. Restart machine
5. Download your provisioning profiles which you require to submit app
6. Open your project and clean it
7. And try again for submit app.

I hope this will work for all.

Comment: Is this maybe a placebo solution? Could it be that doing this took enough time for the server side to fix itself?

Answer (score 14):

I was experiencing the exact same error hence being here (failed about 6 times over an hour).

I just tried again now (without changing anything), it worked by itself.

I read on the Apple-forums that it's an issue with Apple servers, nothing to do with your Xcode.

I also read that others trying the upload via ApplicationLoader (Menu -> Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader), this will ask where your code is, you would then have to select your Archive (not the source code), you can upload your code this way if you need. I personally prefer the built-in Xcode instead.

Works either way.

For the record, I am copying the thread from [Apple Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/35101).

Comment: Can I just add,... to Steve Jobs,... God Bless your soul.... you're gone again, and sadly your company has already started going down hill... so many un-tested not-so-interesting variations of your inventions, I hope someone at Apple start looking into their existing products before launching more convoluted ones.

Comment: Looks like most of the other answers just help spending some time and has no relation with the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Uncheck "Include bitcode" box, worked for me.

Comment: this did it for me

Answer (score 12):

## Update June5 ...

Apple appear to have fixed the ***current particular*** bug that was present for about the last week.

In short, you can upload with the blue "Upload to App Store..." button, rather than having to use the application loader.

---

## For June 1, 2017

even more information, the seemingly failed uploads

## do indeed seem to go to the app store...!

[image]

with each of the items there 208-231, I had tried to upload in the normal way, and it failed with the "Try Again (-22421)" code.

***In fact, unnoticed by me, they were all going up to the app store***, but it looks like they were just getting stuck on endless processing.

I then did I believe exactly what StevenOjo reported (yesterday) above:

- Setting up an A NEW account on iTunes with a NEW email address
- ALSO SET THAT UP ON DEVELOPER, remembering that, because Apple is the world's most idiotic organization, developer.apple is totally different from ituneconnect.apple
- From my actual normal account, and this is IN DEVELOPER, NOT ITUNES CONNECT, I invited that new alter ego as an admin
- Exporting the app from the organizer, as an IPA for app store distribution.
- Logging into application loader with that new email and uploading the archive. It worked without any issues.

It's possible it would actually work fine now with my usual account; I don't know.

To be clear, after a very short time (say, two minutes), the final build (ie, 233 above) did indeed become "ready to test" as normal on the app store ..

[image]

All the "dud" uploads seem to be stuck forever on processing.

## The staggering incompetence of Apple has reached "conspiracy theory" levels....

It is *literally not possible to hire programmers and sysadmins, **who are this bad***.

There must be some sort of conspiracy theory, behind the utter fiasco that is Apple's provisioning. Maybe it's some sort of reverse-psychology marketing plot or something ....... who knows.

---

Later the same day:

## I TRIED UPDATING itmstransporter:

I then tried with a new build number using the normal "Upload to the App Store..." cheery blue button.

## It did not work ...

I then tried using **Application Loader** as described above...

## It DID work with ApplicationLoader.

Conclusion ...

## Unfortunately, itmstransporter is probably not relevant.

:/  what a fiasco.

Comment: I've literally been trying to upload for the past 25 hours. Glad to see the date on here.

Comment: Like Andrew, I spent all day and all night last night trying to get this to work. Not only have I lost 7 months of my life from anger-induced stress, Apple has stolen a little portion of my soul away via their provisioning errors. I've actually felt it leave my body. The incompetence of Apple with these generic, confusing, and buggy problems is greater than the incompetence of my father, who had 34 children with 18 different women and completely abandoned me. Just like Apple has abandoned this process.

Comment: @AndrewK, i added some more info: I tested the "itmstransporter" theory.  Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I had to disable the 2 factor authentication from https://appleid.apple.com/ to be able to log in Application loader

Comment: I am facing similar issue. I am uploading my build through Application Loader. App is uploading and Activity tab is showing my build but not appearing in TestFilght. Can't understand what to do, boss and client are eating me.

Answer (score 9):

## For Xcode 8.3.2

i have resolved same issue

> "This action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)"

**using following steps...**

1. Quit your xcode (if open)
2. in Application Folder,
   Xcode 8.3.2 -->Show Package Contents -->Contents -->Application -->Application Loader (Show package contents) -->Contents -->itms -->bin -->iTMSTransporter (right click and Open with Terminal, it will auto start updating...)
   after updating
   open your project, rebuild your archive and upload it again..

## For Xcode 9

issue

> ”This action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)”

has been Resolved in Xcode 9. Now, we can upload app through Xcode Organizer also.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW876

Answer (score 9):

Open Terminal and run:

```
cd ~

mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```



Comment: This worked for me. I've seen this in other forums too... seems to be a fix.

Comment: Excelent! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did an experiment with this, below, for June 1  (scroll down to my answer).  Unfortunately it *does not* seem to be the root problem   :/

Answer (score 9):

The problem can not be solved with xCode Upload Process. I was facing same issues few days ago when submitting few of my apps and all apps showing same error. After many tries, I used Application Loader to upload app and it worked.

1. First go to xcode -> product menu -> archive
2. Select Export for Appstore
3. Save IPA file
4. Now Open Application loader by going to xCode -> xCode Menu -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader
5. Login with the credentials of account, and select the IPA file.

Submit it! It works!

Comment: This works for me. I now prefer using Application Loader because it's got a slightly better UX than XCode. XCode feels like a black box compared to Application Loader.

Answer (score 8):

I've tried to load archive nearly 10 times (with all kinds of cleans and reloads, with different versions and provisioning files), still received the same error. Then suddenly on my next attempt it showed me: "cannot proceed with delivery an existing transporter instance is currently uploading this package", I did the following and it helped:

Basically, you need to clear out the transport tokens. This can happen if you were to close out of Xcode while in the middle of submitting an app to iTunes Connect.

```
/Users/<username>/.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/
```

Delete any .token files in this directory.
If you are unable to find the .token files, this is because they are hidden in Finder. To hide/show hidden files in Finder, use the following Terminal command (TRUE = UNHIDE, FALSE = HIDE):

defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE;killall Finder

Comment: This and restarting Xcode seem to has solved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

I increased build number but the problem remained.

Then,

1. I approved renewed licence agreement at [itunesconnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com).
2. I opened App Store application on my MAC, and clicked update button for "Command Line Tools (OS X 10.11) for XCode, Version 7.3"
3. I opened XCode. Clicked "Product" button on top bar. While tab content is open, I clicked "alt" key of keyboard to make "Clean Build Folder" option visible. I clicked this option.
4. I rebuild my application for the same version that I received below error;

> This action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)

5. This time I received below error when I want to upload new version;

> This action could not be completed. Try again.

6. I clicked Done and clicked blue "Upload to App Store" button again, and upload completed successfully.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the Option+Product trick to clean the build folder (so much easier). This *finally* worked for us... after a computer restart (Xcode wasn't enough) and clean rebuild (not just resubmitting the same one)

Answer (score 7):

```
Tested in Xcode 7.3, 04142016
```

Instead of clicking the blue **Upload to App Store…** button from the Organizer or while Archiving, Xcode offers a better tool to do this, but it is a little hidden and the process is not clear how to use it.

Here is what I documented while submitting our latest iOS application to the App Store:

First, do NOT use the blue **Upload to App Store…** button.

From Xcode's **Xcode: Developer Tools:** menu, select **Application Loader**.

Sign in with appropriate credentials that allow you to upload to the App Store.

When Application Loader shows you its main screen, select the **Choose** button on the lower right of the main window and open your IPA that you exported for the App Store.

Proceed with the submission.

**Why you want to do this:**

1. Detailed app submission error reporting. Exact explanations of submission errors. It tells you what's incorrect in your app that you are trying to submit.
2. You don't have to deal with the insipid error that prompted this question in the first place.
3. It works consistently in my tests where Xcode's **Submit App to Store…** from the **Archive** menu does not.

Comment: I had try both ways but at that time couldn't upload app to AppStore.

Comment: Nimisha, you only stated that it failed. You did not explain how it failed, where in the process it failed or what the error was.  How can we help you if you don't provide this information?  We're not sitting over your desk watching what happened.  We don't know if you don't tell us.

Comment: I have already explain in question that while uploading Archive to AppStore after that uploading process started and came this error like above image i have attached.
This Problem solve in my case.
This issue generated may be because of Apple Server but after some days i try using Application Loader it's Uploaded successfully.
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 5):

Just In case it is same my mistake.

Did you check **both** provisioning profile settings in "your Project" and "your Targets"?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was caused by lack of some of the app icons in the Images.xcassets

Answer (score 5):

Both developers on our team experienced the same problem, from different machines on May 31st 2017. 
I worked around the problem by:

1. Setting up an app specific password on my Apple ID.
2. Exporting the app from the organizer, as an IPA for app store distribution.
3. Logging into application loader with that App Specific password and uploading the archive. It worked without any issues.

What a lovely waste of time. Hopefully these steps work for others and save some time.

Comment: May31st failed to submit with Xcode over 6-7 times in a row (persistence), worked first try with application loader

Answer (score 4):

When you receive error "**Action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)**",
Just try to resubmit same app on iTunes store using XCode again, and you will get the actual error messages next time.

Detailed error message which your received next time will help you what to do actually!!!

If you are receiving same error again and again, you can submit app using **"App Loader"** and it may success to submit.

**[ Take care Point: ]**

Please check your **app version** / **build version** number is greater than previously submitted version. 
You can verify it in Xcode -> Project setting -> General section AND [iTunes-Connect-Account](http://tunesconnect.apple.com/) -> App Package -> Activity tab

Comment: This was true for me "Just try to resubmit same app on iTunes store using XCode again, and you will get the actual error messages next time." In my case it was ITMS-90062 and I need to bump the CFBundleShortVersionString

Comment: Using Application Loader works for me. The Xocde internal upload mechanism is a bit bugged..

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem over and over again. No descriptive description, just the error message that OP posted.

In fact, it was a problem with the build and so had nothing to do with Apple's servers at all, as you might think.

The solution was to go to `Organizer` and `Export` the build, then upload it via `Application Loader`. Here I got the correct error messages. In my case, it was a problem with CocoaPods breaking app extension validations. I solved this and then I could upload my build.

Hope this helps someone like me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It was related to the Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity -> Release which was set to iOS Developer. If has to be set to iOS Distribution in order for Xcode upload to work.

Answer (score 3):

**For June 1 2017**

Certain combined steps from answer of this thread that worked for me. I am writing the process that worked fine for me.

1) Open terminal and run this

cd ~

mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"

iTMSTransporter will then update itself, wait till process completes.

2) Logout the apple account from Xcode preferences account and login again instead of creating new Id on iTunes and developer account.

3) Clean the project and archive then export the app from organiser as an IPA for app store distribution.

4) Logging into application loader with same account and upload the ipa.

5) Process will complete successfully.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following solutions:
Use **Application Loader** to upload your app, as Xcode organizer can't upload file (rejects IPA) sometimes, without genuine reason and it's frequently occurring issue, with Xcode Organizer, that apple could not resolve permanently.

#### Solution for error code: 22421

> - Apple app upload server is not working properly (not in
>   connection or lost connection during file upload). Just wait and try
>   again later (may be after a day).
> - Fluctuation in your network
>   connection, during file upload.
> - You may not have added privacy
>   statements in your info.plist file.

[Cocoa Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html): Here, is list of keys (with privacy statements) that you should consider to add in your info.plist file, if you have used that service in your application.

---

**Nowadays, you may also face, this error code: 90186 (with app loader)**

> - Outdated application loader can be reason of this error. Use [latest Xcode tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) and use application loader from Xcode Tool.
> - Incorrect/invalid provisioning profile, associated with your build. Ensure, your have used correct provisioning profile (A provisioning
>   profile with **Distribution/Production** mode is require. A *Development mode* provisioning profile won't allow your to upload app on store.)

You can find latest Application Loader Tool from latest Xcode Tool: Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is indeed Application Loader.
I can't comment on Naresh's note on this (I'm too much of a newbie to StackOverflow), but am warning you that if you are using Swift, don't the use Xcode ipa generation system. I prefer manual creation of the IPA by:

```
1) zipping 2 folders : a Payload folder that contain your .app and a SwiftSupport folder that you can copy from your Xarchive. 
2) rename the zip to .ipa.
```

Answer (score 2):

Validating the same archive that failed to upload worked for me. Or just Apple's servers came back up.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect a device while the app is building/archiving, your generic device will change to your connected device automatically, and when you are trying to upload to the app store you will have that weird crash.

This:
[image]

will change to this automatically:

[image]

So to answer your question, I don't know if your issue have been caused because you plugged your iOs device while archiving, but you will be able to reproduce that issue if you plug your iOS device while archiving your app. Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 2):

My problem was with the provisional profiles.

So for me it worked:

Go to Xcode preferences -> Accounts -> In my ID Apple Account -> Select "**Download All**"

I checked too, in member center and delete all invalid provisionals profiles and:

1 - Close Xcode

2 - Open Xcode, do clean and build of my project.

3 - Archive my code again.

Answer (score 2):

Check this list **or just keep trying upload!**

- Got to member center
- Check if there are any invalid provisioning profiles (for some reason, my app store distribution profile has become invalid)
- Delete invalid profiles
- Create new ones
- Download and drag on XCode
- Reboot Mac
- Archive => Upload to App Store
- Everything should be fine again

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me after I enabled two-factor authentication in my Apple ID. After I disable two-factor authentication, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For me VPN caused that problem. After I disconnected from it upload was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think my issue was that I had previously attempted to upload the same version number of my application and it either failed for another reason, or I cancelled it myself.

I changed the version of my app to a version which had not been used before. Cleaned my project. Re-archived it, then uploaded with no issues.

......
You need to INCREASE your version number, you can't make it smaller...

Comment: Problem regarding version can't give this error message because if problem  in version then its give us message version & build can't be lesser than current like that.

Comment: ACTUALLY, THIS CAN HELP in unusual cases, like change of team member.

Answer (score 0):

Just close your Xcode and restart your mac.
Then try upload your app again.
It result from the networking problem,not your operation.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this with my xCode 7.3.1, I did below and looks like 22421 is generic error code if Enable Bitcode is checked/selected:

- Removed and regenerated fresh certificates & profiles
- Cleaned project and restarted machine
- Made sure that I have all icons for my watch app and iOS app
- watch image asset/bundle is <5MB
- followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640149/disable-bitcode-for-project-and-cocoapods-dependencies-with-xcode7) to enable or disable Bitcode flag

And achieved.
- Still build gets uploaded only if I uncheck Enable Bitcode (which I don't understand why)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably everything all right with your code/provisioning profiles/Xcode.

I did try once more, and it worked like a charm. I did not change anything.

Please take note that some actions of people replying earlier did take, could not have any effect on this problem but still, it might look like that actions did help. It would work with or without it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Close your xCode and Application Loader,

**Reboot your Mac**.

Now, launch Application Loader and send it.

Answer (score 0):

I was too having this issues, I had uploaded my application and also updated it once but had no issues, but as i was uploading it for the 3rd time, i came across this issue, tried hell lot of things, scratched my head, googled it for hours, kept on trying the whole day, but nothing happened, but next day( a new light came) and my app uploaded on the first attempt.

Feel like there was some issue from apple side(be it there server, there software xCode or there mac).

So don not get dishearten if facing this problem, you can explore diff things with this problem but its just simple thing to correct this issue is to wait for some time take rest and try again.

Comment: Good it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that Xcode wants us to be logged in with our "normal" account to the **App Store app** when it tries to upload an app to the Mac App Store (MAS) via the Organizer window.

Usually, we developers all test our apps using our MAS test account. This seems to switch the logged App Store user, too. For me, this always works fine:

1. **Log in to the App Store app with your normal account.**
2. **Retry the upload via the Xcode Organizer.** Should then work like expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to us.

We were sure the cause is Apple's Christmas holoday (23-27 Dec 2016). But no - we've tried again 5 minutes later and the version passed.

However - the submission button is greyed out due to the holiday.

[image: No submit today my friend]

Comment: you could have inspect element and enable this option and submit for review ;)

Comment: @FahimParkaryeah - we've heard about this hack. However - we felt it was risky since we have no idea what maintenance is Apple performing during the holiday timeout. Better to wait and get in line at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have saved the prepare for submission page under itunesconnect.apple.com for the new version

Answer (score 0):

Flaky network connection ...

I've had this in the past and it eventually just fixed itself.
But this weekend I tried for days consecutively without success.
However, on a hunch, I've just had success now by **changing to a different network** and then submitting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can not be solved with xCode Upload Process. I was facing same issues few days ago when submitting few of my apps and all apps showing same error. After many tries, I used Application Loader to upload app and it worked.

First go to xcode -> product menu -> archive
Select Export for Appstore
Save IPA file
Now Open Application loader by going to xCode -> xCode Menu -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader
Login with the credentials of account, and select the IPA file.
Submit it! It works!

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too. My issue was that I had previously uploaded a build with the same build number.I just increased the build number in Unity and the problem was resolved. As a matter of fact I didn't realise this was the cause until I used Application Loader, which gave a much more informative error message.

Comment: But this guy is using Application Loader... So you cannot base your answer on something else. Then you use application loader and find it's a totally different error - not at all related to this one. So your answer is both incorrect and totally unrelated. Hell, you're not even using the same software.

Comment: @michael you should remove this answer because bad answer causes misleading!

Answer (score -1):

When above problem exists and you have **Two Factor Authentication** enabled, just do the following:

1. go to http://appleid.apple.com and then create your App-Specific Password

[image]

2. Inside **Application Loader** login with your apple id and **App Specific Password** you just created.
3. Upload your ipa to itunesconnect.

Answer (score -2):

After multiple days of waiting and the problem being persistent. I tried multiple solutions and the below worked for me:

Open your Terminal and put this command

> sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared
>
> sudo chown root:wheel /Users/Shared
>
> sudo chmod -R 1777 /Users/Shared

After I put this, everything works normally.

You can read more here http://www.cnet.com/news/itunes-crashing-with-access-privileges-error-in-10-6-7/