# Cannot Validate Update for my App

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, updates

I have been working on an update for my app that I recently released to the iOS app store. In Xcode, validating and uploading my app worked fine when I first uploaded my app but now, as I am trying to update it, it does not seem to work. I have changed the Version Number and even the Build Number but this does not seem to work. My new app version on iTunes connect is in the "Prepare for Submission" state. When my app fails to validate in Xcode I get this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5ATi.jpg)

If anyone can help with this it would be much appreciated if you could post an answer.

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: It is not the code that is the problem look at the image (click the "enter image description here" button)

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421) shed any light?

Comment: Hi trojanfoe, Thank you so much I have been trying to upload to the app store for 3 days now what you have just told me has worked!