# iTunes Connect Errors occurred in the app thinning process, and your app couldn’t be thinned?

Tags: ios, xcode7, app-store-connect

I Uploaded the build via Xcode Yesterday it worked fine but while uploading today the build is uploading perfectly but after 10 minutes i got a email form apple stating that.

> While processing your iOS app, ---------------Build(1.0.22), errors
>   occurred in the app thinning process, and your app couldn’t be
>   thinned. If your app contains bitcode, bitcode processing may have
>   failed. Because of these errors, this build of your app will not be
>   able to be submitted for review or placed on the App Store. For
>   information that may help resolve this issue, see Tech Note 2432.

I only changed the one line of code and changed the Build Number. And, I uploaded 4 build got the same Error.

Comment: Try To contact Apple Support for the same as Well.

Comment: I've disabled bitcode and tried three times but still facing this issue

Comment: "This happens because Apple's servers may not working correctly. Just wait and try later or next time. It will work for sure finally." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421

Comment: Same problem with Xcode 8 beta.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39415383/961136

Comment: Had the same problem, i was trying on a friday evening, fed up and than started again on Monday and my build got accepted. Dont know something wrong with the Apple's Servers maybe

Answer (score 2):

I met with this issue today, I used google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest (as framework).
I tried all the solutions above, but failed.

Now I fixed it by copying all the source of google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest to my own project. Hope it helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

MY SOLUTION THAT DID NOT WORKED BUT MAYBE CAN GIVE U A WAY OUT

In My own case, i developed my IOS APP with PhoneGap

After so much research, was told to disable bitcode from my ItuneConenct App Account https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html

And was introduced to a new phonegap plugin to disable bitcode in my IOS APP https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cs-disable-bitcode

which i added to my Phonegap app config.xml file

Yet after rebuilding my phonegap IOS app and uploading to ItunesConenct using Application Builder (Got a successful message from the upload). Few mins' after the upload, I got same message from Apple with the same error.

This can give you a hint

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work.  In our case, the error was in one of the embedded frameworks.  Generating a Production Ad-hoc build and then trying to export it generated an error message that pointed us to an error in a setting within one of the framework files. The framework has been there for a while and we never had any issues with it until this release.

Comment: howd you find out it was generating an ad hoc build

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found the solution. In my app, I had the Google Plus framework: GoogleOpenSource.framework. This framework was the problem. I searched about the latest update in Google Plus: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/upgrading-sdk.

The latest version was 1.7.1. This version has the same problem. In my app, I removed the login with Google Plus (deprecated https://gyazo.com/685a58f98ee0b0fca16a6bd83636aad8) and I added Google: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/

This works for me.

A greeting.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Apple Success Message for my App]

Hey guyz My App has been approved by Apple Store. 
The trick i used was this

> Deleted the plugin folder on my App root directory before building
>      [image]
>
> Because most plugins were not compatible with  Apple has to use just few of them on my manifest file

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" /> 
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" /> 
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
```

i was surprised when Apple sent me a message that my App has been Approved just now.

I Home this trick work for someone

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this problem recently, i.e. since September 2016, it may be due to having a 'special character' in the title of your app.

I had several targets for the same code, some of which would process OK and some of which would fail.  The ones that were failing all had Apple symbols in the title, for example one app was called ' Flags'.

Credit to Krati Rastogi: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2205923

Comment: Dude, you saved me! I was totally desperate till saw your answer. My app display name contained emoji at the end. Removed the emoji character and all good. But I have another app with the same type of naming, that compiles fine!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen a couple days ago and the temporary solution for me was to not include bitcode for iOS content, which is an uploading option (see image). Apple suggests to do an ad hoc export with an ad hoc provisioning profile to receive the errors and logs of the failure, but I'm unable to reproduce the error(s) and the ad hoc export is successful each time. Will update this post when I find out how to re-enable bitcode, but for now this seems like a good temporary fix. -Update: there was an error in the name of one of my project folders, mixup with symbolic folder name, when I corrected the name to match what was actually in the folder structure I was able to upload properly- 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As another user above stated...  Remove the Plug In Directory and it solves the problem!

I just uploaded a fully functional version of my App with all of my Plug Ins.  When I use build.phonegap.com to compile my IPA file, I have no Plugin folder in the ZIP file.   The plugins are correctly referenced in my config.xml file.

It works!

I have no clue why this was ever an issue, but that is the ticket to move forward!

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same symptoms and have found a solution.

The root cause of the issue is invalid/incorrect keys in a given bundle's embedded Info.plist.

This is typically the `.bundle` contained within a third party library e.g. GoogleMaps SDK.

The steps for remediation are:

- For each `.bundle` containing only resources:

  - Remove the key/value `CFBundleExecutable`
  - Change the value for key
    `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms` to `iPhoneOS` (Item 0, first element in the array. The previous value was `iPhoneSimulator` in my case)

The technical reason is that `CFBundleExecutable` should not be present in a bundle's plist if there is no executable. The value for `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms` is self explanatory, it should be `iPhoneOS`.

[Tech Note 2432](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2432/_index.html) mentions the above two keys but does not elaborate how to resolve the issue.

I hope this solution works for you.

Comment: Try removing the Plugin Folder and let the references in the config.xml pull in the Plugins as needed.  I just found it worked for me!

Comment: I did removed the mentioned key, app is in processing state for 2 hours now, but no update yet. Rest of the values were same as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made this work!!!

Just like **@applejack42**  said, you must remove **CFBundleExecutable** key of all 3rd party library info.plist file.

In my case, I just remove this key from JSONModel info.plist, and submit.

Success!

I really hope it works for you, because that issue make me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

update xcode to 8.0 which published at 0914 from apple store , rebuild project and submit to iturns , the issue was not found , instead any detail info for anouther issue which use ios 10 sdk required . i have submited success, and waiting for approval .

Answer (score 0):

Ive attempted various build and submitted to Itunes with Xcode 8 and 7, with no success.

Deleting my plugins folder was not the solution, neither was greping through all my .plist's to find the CFBundleExecutable. At this moment its just waiting on further discovery from the community and or returning to our 3rd party resources and asking them to update their libs which may not be as easy as apple is suggesting us to do.

To identify the affected libraries I built to an iPhone with Bitcode enabled and in my case their are three libs that need updating. This may not be the best solution but if you need an explanation for your superiors this may save you some time in identifying what needs updating.

I will update my thread as I continue along this road.

Comment: this makes me very sad... right now made the jump to xcode 8 (causing us a ton of grief as is already) and we're hoping at the end of it we can upload a build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommends to test by archiving the app first and then exporting the app for **ad hoc distribution**. If there are errors, you can then see this in the logs, you can access them from the export dialog.

My favorite solution, if there is no error during export:

1. update cocoapods
2. run pod install
3. clean the project and resubmit

It just worked for me, no clue why, but it might be worth a try instead of wasting hours on finding a solution for a non existant problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me the Issue was that one of my frameworks wasn't embedded and signed . hope that might help someone

Answer (score 0):

I have met with this situation with Xamarin IOS Project in Visual Studio

I have solved in

1. Clean All
2. Rebuild All

then archive your project