# iTunesConnect: Processing stopped for App submitted to testflight

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, xcode7.3

Since today, each time I upload a build to Appstore with Application Loader my app is rejected on the basis of App Thinning error. I've tried to disable bitcode and upload build again but no use. Can someone help me on this error?
[image]

Comment: I am facing same issue, in my case I cannot remove sdks or enable bitcode as they are too many. Its there any wayout?

Comment: @NaXir so in my case i enabled bitcode to see which ones failed, it was just google maps, i went to the change log and noticed that there was a fix regarding bitcode, try updating all your pods and then build and see if that decreases errors.

Comment: Please see my answer, I already solved this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390546/itunes-connect-errors-occurred-in-the-app-thinning-process-and-your-app-couldn/39484306#39484306

Answer (score 2):

After trying for 24 hours and sending like 10+ builds, I finally enabled bitcode in my project and got rid of sdks(in my case it was GooglePlus) which were not supporting bitcode. My build is accepted now. I'm not aware why Apple has imposed this thing all of sudden. Maybe they did mentioned it somewhere and I failed to pick it up.

Comment: I also tried enabling bitcode and it was the GooglePlus framework that was causing issues for building the app. With bitcode disabled the build went good but I got the reported error several times. I guess its the GooglePlus framework and also many others (as I've stumbled upon many people with this same exact error from Apple) that cause this problem. Hopefully Apple will fix it in the near future since I can't remove the Google Plus framework, it's crucial for my app.

Comment: I don't know what functionality of G+ u're using. I was using Signin and friends in circle thing. I was already using GIDSIGNIN instead of GPPSIGNIN so it was easy. Next I started using Rest API for retrieving friends.