# TestFlight. Upload build issue

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I'm the only one stupid? Since yesterday evening I am trying to upload to TestFlight my project and see ...

> Dear XXXXXX, While processing your iOS app, XXXXXX 1.0(2685), errors
>   occurred in the app thinning process, and your app couldn’t be
>   thinned. If your app contains bitcode, bitcode processing may have
>   failed. Because of these errors, this build of your app will not be
>   able to be submitted for review or placed on the App Store. For
>   information that may help resolve this issue, see Tech Note 2432.
>   Regards, The App Store team

iOS 10 problems ?
but validation is successful

bit code = off, privacy keys -> set & Two days ago it was Ok, project code is not changed

Thanks in advance for answers

Comment: [TN 2432](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2432/_index.html) provides troubleshooting for the problem and a list of known issues. Have you checked that out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTunes Connect Errors occurred in the app thinning process, and your app couldn’t be thinned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390546/itunes-connect-errors-occurred-in-the-app-thinning-process-and-your-app-couldn)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Validation is successful but a few minutes later I receive the same e-mail. I've tried enabling and disabling bitcode but that doesn't help. Tech Note troubleshooting was not helpful.

Comment: same issue for me, looks like this is a wide spread issue

Comment: Having the same issue here. Will let you all know if we find a resolution.

Comment: Mail from apple support: