# Xcode archive failed to upload

Tags: xcode8, archive

Hey guys I have been getting this error on Xcode ALL DAY long today! I don't know how to fix it. I'm on Xcode 8.

"This action could not be completed. Try again (-22421)"

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again later. It's a bug from Apple's side.