# This action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421) (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I have tried to upload my app to App Store (iTunes Connect) to test my app in TestFlight, but always appears the same error message. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong. It´s the third day I´m trying to upload my app.

Also read that this is a problem from Apple's servers, but every day is the same problem.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: try solutions provided in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421

Comment: Thanks Amod, I have done it with Application Loader. First export the .ipa file, and then proccesed in Application Loader to visualize in iTunes Connect.

Comment: so it solved your problem? Update answer with solution so that others can be benefited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done it with Application Loader. First export the .ipa file, and then proccesed in Application Loader to visualize in iTunes Connect. Never works with Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following solutions:
Use **Application Loader** to upload your app, as Xcode organizer can't upload file (rejects IPA) sometimes, without genuine reason and it's frequently occurring issue, with Xcode Organizer, that apple could not resolve permanently.

**Solution to error code: 22421**

> - Apple app upload server is not working properly (not in
>     connection or lost connection during file upload). Just wait and try
>     again later (may be after a day).
> - Fluctuation in your network
>     connection, during file upload.
> - You may not have added privacy
>     statements in your info.plist file.

[Cocoa Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html): Here, is list of keys that you should consider to add in your info.plist file, if you have used that service in your application.

**Nowadays, you may also face, this error code: 90186 (with app loader)**

> - Outdated application loader can be reason of this error. Use [latest Xcode tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) and use application loader from Xcode Tool.
> - Incorrect/invalid provisioning profile, associated with your build. Ensure, your have used correct provisioning profile (A provisioning
>     profile with **Distribution/Production** mode is require. A *Development mode* provisioning profile won't allow your to upload app on store.)

You can find latest Application Loader Tool from latest Xcode Tool: Xcode ▶ Open Developer Tool ▶ Application Loader

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cd ~  
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/  
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/ApplicationLoader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```