# iOS - Error: This action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, upload, app-store

I am trying to upload an iOS App to the App Store, using **Xcode >> Organizer**, but I got the issue This Action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421) as in the below image.
I tried to re-upload app many times but same error occurred

Here is snaps for an issue I'm getting :

[image]

What to do next? How can I upload my app successfully on store?

Tried using Application Loader app and now getting another error

> Error ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid.

Comment: This error at times comes because of network issues. How are you uploading build, via Xcode or application loader ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421?rq=1

Comment: what are u using to upload the app? There might be two know situation 1. Apple server is not working properly 2. Just export the IPA file & upload via Application Loader.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421)

Comment: upload app both way(using xcode, application loader)
in application loader error occurred "the binary you uploaded was invalid."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Application Loader** to upload your app, as Xcode organizer can't upload file (rejects IPA) sometimes, without genuine reason and it's frequently occurring issue, with Xcode Organizer, that apple could not resolve permanently.

There are few other reasons also for such kind of error, like

> - Apple app upload server is not working properly (not in
>     connection or lost connection during file upload). Just wait and try
>     again later (may be after a day).
> - Fluctuation in your network
>     connection, during file upload.
> - You may not have added privacy
>     statements in your info.plist file.

[Cocoa Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html): Here, is list of keys that you should consider to add in your info.plist file, if you have used that service in your application.

**Solution for error code: 90186**

> - Outdated application loader can be reason of this error. Use [latest Xcode tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) and use application loader from Xcode Tool.
> - Incorrect/invalid provisioning profile, associated with your build. Ensure, your have used correct provisioning profile (A provisioning
>     profile with **Distribution/Production** mode is require. A *Development mode* provisioning profile won't allow your to upload app on store.)

You can find latest Application Loader Tool from latest Xcode Tool: Xcode (Menu) ► Open Developer Tool ► Application Loader

[image]

Comment: upload app both way(using xcode, application loader) in application loader error occurred "the binary you uploaded was invalid."

Comment: Is there any error code with this error ? Please share error code. It may be ITMS: 9000 or 90686

Comment: Error ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with application loader. You will have to create ur ipa from the Xcode organizer and use application loader.

I am facing this issue for the last week. finally uploaded using application loader.

Comment: upload app both way(using xcode, application loader) in application loader error occurred "the binary you uploaded was invalid."