# iOS - App not getting uploaded to Apple server

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been trying to submit a Swift 3 app to Apple from Xcode 8.2 , App passes through all phases but gets stuck at authentication forever and then ends with an error. But then I export app for Appstore submission and then upload the same using Application Loader, tried with two different accounts but no avail. Have referred to this thread as well [This action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421)

Most upvoted answer says apple servers may be misbehaving but I wonder how many days ? Is this something specific to Swift app ? I havent tried submitting any ObjC app recently so not sure, can anyone provide a solution ?

Comment: I had the same problem one hour ago. I retried to upload my app 10min ago and it worked! Apple servers, in my opinion... :)

Comment: @Toldy I have used it two hours ago and switched to loader , but last week struggled the same whole day , I wonder how can that be Apple server

Comment: @Krunal what solution you got ?

Comment: 1. There was no solution from my (our) end at that time, as issue with upload server of Apple. So they took a time of 3 days and solved uploading issue. (For 7 days my bug request was in queue)

Comment: 2. Second time, I missed Privacy statements, so apple developer committee suggested me to add privacy statement (for Camera) in info.plist

Answer (score 1):

I stopped using Xcode uploader after 2 hours of failed uploading attempts. Then I took Application Loader instead and it told me the exact reason of fails. In my case it was too fat watch extension.
Hope this will help.

Comment: In my case loader doesn't tell any reason but it still takes more than 5 minutes to authenticate on fairly good connection .

Answer (score 1):

It's ongoing issue with Apple App uploader server, since couple of days, so you don't have a way, rather than waiting.

You can try following solutions:
Use **Application Loader** to upload your app, as Xcode organizer can't upload file (rejects IPA) sometimes, without genuine reason and it's frequently occurring issue, with Xcode Organizer, that apple could not resolve permanently.

**Solution for error code: 22421**

> - Apple app upload server is not working properly (not in
>     connection or lost connection during file upload). Just wait and try
>     again later (may be after a day).
> - Fluctuation in your network
>     connection, during file upload.
> - You may not have added privacy
>     statements in your info.plist file.

[Cocoa Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html): Here, is list of keys that you should consider to add in your info.plist file, if you have used that service in your application.

**Nowadays, you may also face, this error code: 90186 (with app loader)**

> - Outdated application loader can be reason of this error. Use [latest Xcode tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) and use application loader from Xcode Tool.
> - Incorrect/invalid provisioning profile, associated with your build. Ensure, your have used correct provisioning profile (A provisioning
>     profile with **Distribution/Production** mode is require. A *Development mode* provisioning profile won't allow your to upload app on store.)

You can find latest Application Loader Tool from latest Xcode Tool: Xcode ▶ Open Developer Tool ▶ Application Loader

[image]