# Xcode Archive upload failed with errors

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a new build to iTunesConnect from xCode, but every time I encounter this issue:

[image]

What is the problem? and how can I fix this?

Comment: hi i have facing same problem you got solution for this error?

Comment: @Birendra Yes, the first solution worked with me. I uploaded it using Application Loader.

Comment: ok thanks i will try it

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Cant login into Application Loader -_-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently I started facing issues during upload progress and Xcode used to get stuck a lot and would eventually fail with the second error which you are seeing. Having fed up for a while, I switched to use Application Loader in XCode.

Way to use would be, first archive your app, once that is finished, you can spot `Export` option on the right hand side panel just below `Upload to App Store` option. After you select Export You will see different options. Select `Save for iOS App Deployment`. This will create a .ipa file and save it in your desired location.

Now, go to XCode -> Developer Tools -> Application Loader -> Deliver Your App -> Select the .ipa file where you had saved before.

This method has been helping me a lot and failed not even once for quite sometime. Hope it helps you as well.

Comment: best detailed steps... the .ipa and application loader is the only working since yesterday. Have been trying since yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to Apple server is not working correctly for now, try to upload it later or 1 day after, it will be uploaded successfully, it happens due to Apple's app server internal problem.

Also you can try to upload it through App Loader. but if apple's server is in trouble then uploaded binary may not shown in iTunesconnect.

Answer (score 1):

It would only work if I used Application Loader, like this:

First, export the application Archive from Xcode's Organizer window (it saves this into a directory on the Desktop).

Then, from Xcode:

Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader