# ITMS-90668 - Invalid Bundle Executable. The executable file contains incomplete bitcode

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bitcode

Yesterday I started to get strange error message from iTunes Connect:

```
ITMS-90668
Invalid Bundle Executable.
The executable file '...' contains incomplete bitcode.
To compile binaries with complete bitcode, open Xcode and choose Archive in the Product menu.
```

Actually, I am getting many identical messages for each of my embedded frameworks.

I do use Bitcode, and I have not changed anything related Bitcode in my project. 
It seems like a new ITMS requirement (or bug). And I have no idea how to fix it.

Looks like this problem mysteriously related to CI tools like Shenzhen or BuddyBuild. Or, maybe, it is related to cases when dependencies contain precompiled code.

Just in case, my app:

- Has these dependencies which have precompiled code:
  **BuddyBuildSDK**, **Firebase**, **CardIO**.
- Written in Swift.
- Has iOS Keyboard Extension.
- Use BuddyBuild.
- Use CocoaPods.

## Update:

I had changed virtually nothing and then the problem did disappear yesterday. I have no idea why exactly. I believe Apple just fixed that bug or it is fluke problem.

Comment: Same here, came all of a sudden out of the blue. I've tried setting bitcode to YES and NO both variants - no change.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. How are you submitting your code to iTunes Connect?

Comment: Getting same issue , I think this is a Apple's bug. Is any report have been done?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with some pod dependencies. I changed "Enable Bitcode" build setting for each pod projects causing the issue (following the error descriptions from itunesconnect). Now everything works.

You can set it in the Podfile. Here an example that changes for each dependencies:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Found here: [Disable bitcode for project and cocoapods dependencies with Xcode7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640149/disable-bitcode-for-project-and-cocoapods-dependencies-with-xcode7)

Comment: So, is this issue related to buddybuild?!

Comment: I don't think so. I used the error description back from itunesConnect in buddybuild. I think Apple has changed the applications validations rules.

Comment: Ok, that's nice temporary workaround but I do want to use Bitcode, so obviously I don't want to disable it.

Comment: I understand, you can just disable bitcode for pod libraries with problems. If I find a solution to reactivate it, I'll share it.

Comment: This worked for me. Does anyone know why this error has just started appearing? We haven't changed any bitcode related settings in a few releases...

Answer (score -3):

Just register a problem in the git card.io library:
https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/205

I hope to resolve this situation as soon as possible!

Comment: Is there any clue that this problem is related to Card.io?