# Swift "Invalid Mach-O Format" Error

Tags: ios, swift, mach-o, bitcode

**Invalid Mach-O Format**

I have a Universal Framework which has `i386 and x86_64` architectures for iOS Simulator also `armv7 and arm64` architectures for iOS Device. It works perfectly in my project.

When I submit the application to App Store, I have to remove the unwanted architectures `(i386 and x86_64)`. I have removed those two architectures using the shell Script.

While submitting to App Store, I got the following error.

[image]

I have given `"Enable Bitcode" = "Yes"` in both my framework and project. 
In my framework the `"Mach-O Type" = "Dynamic Library"` and In the project the `"Mach-O Type" = "Executable"`.

Similar question is available at

[Xcode - Error ITMS-90635 - Invalid Mach-O in bundle - submitting to App store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613550/xcode-error-itms-90635-invalid-mach-o-in-bundle-submitting-to-app-store)

In that question their main bundle has armv7 & arm64 (machine code), In my question the main bundle contains armv7 & arm64 (bitcode)

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Not exactly, In that question, they ended up in a solution setting "Enable Bitcode"= "No". In my case, I don't want to disable bit code

Comment: Try to uncheck `Include bytecode` checkbox in `Send YourProjectName to Apple` form on previous step