# Xcode - Warning ITMS-90735 - Invalid Executable Section - submitting to App store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, itunes

[image]

when uploading app to appstore, we're getting below warning in apploader log.

```
WARN: WARNING ITMS-90735: "Invalid Executable Section. As of October 1, 2018 apps must no longer contain executables that have a __DATA,__dyld section. The Mach-O file in bundle with identifier 'com.myapp' has the invalid section (__DATA,__dyld)."
```

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is high likely due to different BITCODE settings in your app dependencies. E.g. your app has `ENABLE_BITCODE` set to `NO` but one of your dependencies is set to `YES`.

Please refer to this answer for more details: [Xcode - Error ITMS-90635 - Invalid Mach-O in bundle - submitting to App store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613550/xcode-error-itms-90635-invalid-mach-o-in-bundle-submitting-to-app-store)

Comment: Thanks for valuable inputs. I'll try this out.