# Unable to Archive iOS Project in XCode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to archive a project in Xcode (9.2) and I Get the below error.

```
ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/myUser/Documents/iOSApps/Test/Pods/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF/Internal/libAWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF.a(AWSCognitoIdentityASF.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Based on other StackOverflow answers, I have set `Enable BitCode -> No` within my App Build Settings

Below is the image of the `BitCode settings` in the App.  However, I still get the above error. Could some one please help me resolve this issue ?

[image]

Comment: did u remove the Derived data?

Comment: Yeah, I did remove the derived data.

Comment: Looking at the error it looks like one of your pod `AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF` is built without bitcode support. So disabling it for the whole project should do it! check this thread and try disabling bitcode for all the pods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640149/disable-bitcode-for-project-and-cocoapods-dependencies-with-xcode7/32640217