# BitCode bundle could not be generated in react native ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

i am making a build for react -native project on ios platform.The project is working fine in android and also on the simulator on ios.Now when i am about to make the archive for the ios build in the xcode it gives me error

> bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/webmobril/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj-bjydvwozceoqvtdoxbwrslcvdyqm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Fuelex/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTLinkedinLogin.a(Pods-dummy.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '/Users/webmobril/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj-bjydvwozceoqvtdoxbwrslcvdyqm/Build/Intermediates.noind

I have tried deleting derived data and also setting bitcode to no. But it does not work

Comment: try this: close xcode and delete this folder `/Users/webmobril/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` then `pod update` and `pod install` if it not work check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640149/disable-bitcode-for-project-and-cocoapods-dependencies-with-xcode-7

Comment: that means i have to diasble bitocde in projects build setting ! am i right ?