# Bridging header import can't find target. How to correctly import?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently trying to implement Google Cloud Messaging library to my IOS app. I am following the instructions [from here.](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift)

However I am having issues with bridging header.
[This is how my project structure looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF1Ty.png)

But when I try to build the project, it says

```
GoogleCloudMessaging.h file not found
```

I also tried the header like this:

```
#import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>
```

But it did not work as well. How do I successfully import that to my project?

Comment: Did you add it in Build Phase as a compile source?

Comment: I did, I know it works because it successfully navigates in to header file and tries to import GoogleCloudMessaging, then fails.

Comment: if you are working on swift project and use gcm then you just need to use pod not import like that

Comment: I imported with pod actually. But instructions said I needed a bridging header. I added pod 'Google/CloudMessaging' line to my Podfile. Successfully builded the project. After that I usually import the added library and it works. But google cloud messaging did not show up on imports.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few minutes ago. I resolved it by searching 'bridging' and found another bridging header file. I then #imported the line of code in there. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Nope the one I created is the only bridging-header in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Like the solution to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219849/google-cloud-messaging-bridging-header-import-fails?rq=1), try to update your cocoa pods and check if the error is gone. Also check this SO question [Failed to import bridging header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116288/failed-to-import-bridging-header?rq=1) and [Xcode not automatically creating bridging header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716413/xcode-not-automatically-creating-bridging-header?rq=1) for more information and maybe another workaround to your problem.